# Why can't I see my shellcode executing in Immunity Debugger?

Tags: exploit, shellcode, windows-server, assembly

I am doing an exercise on creating custom shellcode (windows). The goal is to create shellcode that will delete the firewall log file.
I successfully spawned a reverse shell with metasploit, using a python program I wrote, but when I try writing my own shellcode I am not successful yet. It's partly because Immunity is behaving in a strange way:

Reaching a certain point in the execution, Immunity exits. Yet when I press pause and step into again, I can see my filepath string in ebx. So my shellcode was executed, but I can't see the instructions being executed.

If you can help with immunity's behavior I would appreciate it...

[image: Immunity exit]

[image: String in EBX]

[image: Here is a snapshot of the shellcode]

Comment: Did you check for bad characters ?

Comment: you'd probably have better luck in stack overflow. While this is security-related, programming is more stack overflow's area of expertise.